# What is a simple way to interact with a Python script through a web page?

Tags: python, web, server, frontend, backend

I have a elaborate Python script that does some image processing (opencv) and hardware management (sensors and motors) on a Raspberry Pi 4.

I'd like to have a web-page (hosted locally on the Pi) that people can go to by typing an address and getting an interactive UI to manage the script.

My question is about the web-page part: I am a complete noob in web development. What would be the easiest, fastest way to:

1. Prepare a webpage without coding
2. Host that page locally and give people access to it
3. Make the Python script output results to that page and be able to receive UI requests from the page (like buttons, data etc.)

Thank you.

Comment: `Prepare a webpage without coding` pay someone else to code it for you. `Host that page locally and give people access to it` use a web-server application (which you've paid the person creating the site for you to set up of course).

Comment: There are many web frameworks. Just choose one and have a go.

Comment: It's mostly about question 3

Comment: There are many python web frameworks. Just search and choose one and have a go. Requesting software/libraries/frameworks is off-topic on StackvOverflow.